# How to get OAuth2 work with Google and the Play Framework using Java

Tags: oauth, playframework

I am trying to get my Play application use Google authentication via OAuth2.  My goal is once the user logs into Google, they will be able to access my Play application.  As of now, my application uses its own authentication process (login form, User model, etc.).  I would also like to grab the Google account info and compare against the User model in my application.

I see many posts on samples on how to get this implemented.  A few have been ruled out since it must be in Java.

What is the best and easiest way to get the Play application to read the Google account info?  I was hoping to see a sample using Java, Google, and Play.

As for the Google side, I have a project set up and need to follow these instructions:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

I am hoping there is some code out there that I can use and reverse engineer.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Silhouette, https://www.silhouette.rocks/, is one of the most popular authentication libraries for Play Framework applications. It supports Facebook, Google, Linkedin, etc.

These are some templates you might want to try by yourself.
https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/examples

Comment: Looks like it uses Scala instead of Java...  Looking for a Java solution...

Comment: The question specifically refers to PLAY-JAVA but the answer is relevant for PLAY-SCALA.